# What sequence was I thinking of?

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

Ten years ago I blogged:

> I picked up my old, battered copy of
>   G.H. Hardy's *Pure Mathematics*.  I haven't spent as much
>   time reading this book as I should have; it's full of good stuff.
>   There didn't seem to be anything in there about the Gaussian
>   integers (digression: What's next in the sequence 1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 14,
>   16, 24, 26?) but while scanning the index I noticed there was an entry
>   for Ramanujan, so I checked it out.

What *is* next in the sequence 1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 14,
16, 24, 26? I can't remember.  Google search finds only this one mention from my blog.  OEIS doesn't know; the best I can do is [A228898](http://oeis.org/A228898) which I'm sure is not what I had in mind.  There is probably something to it, and the answer will not be of the type "If you use Lagrange interpolation to fit the following 9th-degree polynomial… the next value is -163”, or the stops on the 7th avenue IRT train, or anything similarly obnoxious.

It must have something to do with Hardy's book, but I have no idea what.

Comment: If $20$ were in that sequence, I'd say the next number after $26$ would be $36$. Are you sure you didn't accidentally forget $20$? (It would fit Gaussian integers, though, not Hardy's book.)

Comment: That is surely the answer: [“nonnegative integers such that $a(n)+i$ is a Gaussian prime”](http://oeis.org/A005574).   Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Daniel Fischer's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095324/what-sequence-was-i-thinking-of?noredirect=1#comment4306991_2095324) is almost certainly the right answer:

> If 20 were in that sequence, I'd say the next number after 26 would be 36. Are you sure you didn't accidentally forget 20?

because these are positive integers $n$ such that $n+i$ is a gaussian prime.  Or, more simply, $n^2+1$ is prime. See [OEIS A005574](http://oeis.org/A005574).

Perhaps I computed the values by hand and made a mistake on $20+i$.